# Android Studio 3.3.2 Layout change not working

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to Android Studio, Android and currently coding in Kotlin. I tried changing and deleting code even the XML file and run, the AVD still showing me the same layout. Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image: the picture is here]

Comment: UPDATE: I tried create a new project and it worked again

Comment: Pay attention to which layout you're inflating in the Activity with the line `setContentView()`. My guess is you had two layout files and you were inflating the wrong one.

Comment: @GavinWright I'm pretty sure I inflate the correct layout

Comment: It isn't just the layout file that determines the final UI, there could be elements added in code too. Check the activity to make sure the button isn't being added there. Often when you create a new activity in AS it'll generate some extra UI code.